# PHP Regular Expression to remove all single-digit integers

Tags: php, regex

How would this be implemented with `preg_replace`, replacing the matched regular expression?

For example, I would want the string:

`There was a movie made of Alan Turing's life in 2014 8`

to be replaced with

`There was a movie made of Alan Turing's life in 2014`

without replacing the four-digit numbers of the year, or any other non-one-digit number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use word boundary `\b` here:

```
$s = "There was a movie made of Alan Turing's life in 2014 8";

$s = preg_replace('#\b\d\b#', '', $s);
//=> There was a movie made of Alan Turing's life in 2014
```

`\b\d\b` will match any single digit but won't match more than one digit number.

Comment: Thank you! I wish I was a `regex` matching pro!

Comment: Yes, it did! I'm impressed by your reputation, by the way. How long do you spend answering questions every day?

Comment: There is no dedicated time for this, some tags of SO remain in background while I work. I think I spend on an average 2-3 hrs/day.